# How to ask te user and depending on his response run all the code again?

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, try-catch

I'm a newbie in Java. I started these days and I'm practicing the catch and try exception. I have this code below  which solve an operation between to numbers and I'd like to know what can I do, if for example I want that the user, once he makes an operation and get his result, that this has the possibility to make another operation. something like comes up a question asking if he wants to realize another problem and the code run again from the beginning.

```
package justpractice;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Operation = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x=1;

    while(x==1){
        try{
            System.out.println("Insert numerator");
            int n1 = Operation.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Insert denominator");
            int n2=Operation.nextInt();
            double division = n1/n2;
            System.out.println(division);
            x=2;

    }

    catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Insert a valid value");
    }
    }
}



}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your division will always result in a whole number since you are dividing integers

Answer (score 0):

You can do, for example, adding an if statement with a

```
System.out.println("Do you want to recalculate ? (1/0 Yes/No)");
Operation.nextInt();
```

then if the input is 1, keep x = 1, else do x = 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code amendment;

```
package justpractice;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Operation = new Scanner(System.in);

    //better practice
    while(true){
        try{
            System.out.println("Insert numerator");
            int n1 = Operation.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Insert denominator");
            int n2=Operation.nextInt();
            double division = n1/n2;
            System.out.println(division);
            System.out.println("Continue? (y/n)");
            String response = Operation.nextLine();
            if (response.equals("n")){
               break;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Insert a valid value");
        }
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow your user to calculate division again, you could use a [`do-while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop. With this loop you can execute the code inside once, ask the user if they would like to calculate again, and repeat the code if they do.

An outline of your code with the loop would something like this:

```
...
boolean again = true;

do { //Main loop
    try {
        ... //Your division code
        ... //Put code to ask the user if they want to calculate again here
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ...
    }
} while(again == true); //Repeat if the user wants to continue
```

To get input on if the user wants to calculate again, I recommend using another `do-while` loop with your `Scanner`. This loop will allow you to repeat the code when the answer is invalid. In this case, when it's not `"y"` or `"n"`.

```
String input;
do {
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (y/n)");
    input = operation.next();
} while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
```

After you have got the user's input, you still need to terminate the loop if they said `"n"`. To do this you could use an `if` statement.

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
    again = false; //Terminate the main loop
    operation.close(); //Prevent any resource leaks with your Scanner
}
```

There is no need to check if the user input `"y"` as `again` is set to `true` by default.

Side Note: Variables should always be camelCase. Look at the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) to learn more about naming things in Java.

**EDIT:**
The reason the console is repeatedly logging that you entered a non-number even though you entered it once, I'm not exactly sure. I *think* it's because the call to `nextInt()` never finishes because of the `InputMismatchException` being thrown, causing the next call to `nextInt()` (After the `do-while` repeats) to think that the letter/symbol you just entered is the one you want to process, repeating the exception over and over again.

To solve this, add this line into your `catch` block:

```
if(operation.hasNext()) operation.next();
```

This will call `next()` and complete the process of marking the letter/symbol you just entered as already processed, then repeat the `do-while` loop as normal.